# How to delete the contents of a related record from two tables?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

The `StudentDetails.Students` is the master table which forms a relationship with  `RegistrationDetails.Registration`. Therefore, `StudentID` is the primary key in the former whereas it is a foreign key in the latter.

Now I've tried each of the following codes but each of the first two gives an error message "Incorrect syntax near 'a'" and in the case of the third one `DbTransaction` as in "Dim trans As DbTransaction" is also not a valid type. Please I'm using SQL Server 2008 Professional Edition.

1.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM StudentDetails.Students a, RegistrationDetails.Registration b WHERE (b.StudentId=a.StudentId) AND a.StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'", cn)
```

2.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM StudentDetails.Students a, RegistrationDetails.Registration b WHERE (b.StudentId=a.StudentId) AND a.StudentId='/" & txtStudentID.Text & "/'", cn)
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete a row from each table based on the student ID?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to delete records from both tables based on the StudentID on the master table.

Comment: While it may not matter in this case, remember that you're opening yourself for SQL injection when you use `" & txtStudentID.Text & "` instead of SQL Parameters

Answer (score 3):

Don't specify the fields when deleting, delete from 1 table at a time, and wrap everything in a transaction:

```
Dim trans As SqlTransaction

trans = cn.BeginTransaction

Try
  Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("Delete from Registration where StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'", cn)

  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

  Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("Delete from StudentDetails where StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'", cn)

  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

  trans.Commit()
Catch theException As Exception
  ' Report the exception
  trans.Rollback()
End Try
```

Comment: DbTransaction as in "Dim trans As DbTransaction" is not a valid type. Please I'm using SQL Server 2008 Professional Edition.

Comment: Please DbTransaction is being seen as invalid type. I'm using VB 2008 professional Edition.

Comment: @Akaglo: You can change the type to SqlTransaction

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code is working but it deletes a record only from the dependent table (Registration) instead of deleting from both tables.

Comment: @Akaglo: That's very strange. The only thing I can think of is that reusing the command object is somehow confusing the connection. I have modified the answer to use two different command objects, which will remove that as a possibility.

Comment: Thanks very much. I've tried the modified code but strangely the commands execute without deleting any record from both tables. Well is it because the dependent table (Registration) has also got a primary key on a column called "RegdNumber" that's why both codes are not working perfectly? Please help me.

Comment: Are there any exceptions that are raised when the code is executed? If so, we will need to know what these are before we can offer any suggestions. Based on you comment it sounds like the Registration table may be linked to another table.

Comment: Yes, the Registration table is linked to the Student table as a child; that is, the Student table is the master whereas the Registration table is the child and the delete command is executed from the form that is linked to the Student table. However, the Registration table has not yet been linked to any other table, and with both the previous and the modified codes given from you, no exception is raised.

Comment: Alright, I modified the previous code by removing the following "trans = cn.BeginTransaction" and "trans.Rollback()". And the code is now working perfectly. I'm glad. However, I wish you could show me how the code can work without excluding these two important lines.

Comment: @Akaglo: If you only removed those two lines, it sounds like you may have missed the trans.Commit() just before the Catch statement. Can you verify that you had all three lines? If so, then we need to find out what exception was being thrown (step through in debug to see where the code fails, then include information about what exception was thrown here, please).

Comment: I've even removed the Dim trans As SqlTransaction and
the trans.Commit() lines but the code is still able to delete related records from both tables perfectly (without any error or exception being raised). I now just want to know how I can use this SQL Transanction 'stuff' so that in case there is a power failure or system failure during deletion, the delete transaction can 'row back'.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know anything related to .NET, but you should try something like:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Delete from StudentDetails.Students a, RegistrationDetails.Registration b where (b.StudentId=a.StudentId) and a.StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'", cn)
```

Because you delete whole records, not columns, that is why you don't and can't specify column names in the `DELETE` clause

Answer (score 1):

First delete all the records in "Registration" table related to specified StudentId.

Then, delete it from master table "StudentDetails".

and for keeping consistency of your data, use transaction.

Comment: Please show me exactly what I should do by modifying my code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's better to use transaction especially when deleting related data from two tables. Use **parametrisation instead of concatenation** and read more about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_Implementations).

Your code should look more like this:

```
Using c As New SqlConnection("connection string")
    c.Open()
    Using tx As SqlTransaction = c.BeginTransaction()
        Try
            Using cmd As SqlCommand = c.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = "delete from RegistrationDetails.Registration where StudentId = @studentId"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtStudentID.Text
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                cmd.CommandText = "delete from StudentDetails.Students where StudentId = @studentId"
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtStudentID.Text
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                tx.Commit()
            End Using
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            tx.Rollback()
            ' take care of exception here
            Throw
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

I assume that `StudentId` column is `varchar` type (because of using apostrophes in: `a.StudentId='" & txtStudentID.Text & "'"`), if it's not change the `SqlDbType.VarChar` to whatever it is.

Comment: I changed the SqlDbType.VarChar to  SqlDbType.BigInt in conformity to the data type used for the StudentID, but the following error message is constantly being raised. "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Comment: @Akaglo: could you update the question and paste there more code (context in which you are executing SqlCommand).